# SQL querying dataframes inside list

Tags: r, list, dataframe, data.table, sqldf

Given the dataframes

```
df1 <- data.frame(CustomerId=c(1:6),Product=c(rep("Toaster",3),rep("Radio",3)))
df2 <- data.frame(CustomerId=c(2,4,6),State=c(rep("Alabama",2),rep("Ohio",1)))
```

are stored in a list

```
dflist <- c(df1,df2)
```

how do I run sqldf queries (joins) on these dataframes?

Failed attempts:

```
test <- sqldf("select a.CustomerId, a.Product, b.State from dflist[1] a
          inner join dflist[2] b on b.id = a.id")

test <- sqldf("select a.CustomerId, a.Product, b.State from dflist$df1 a
          inner join dflist$df2 b on b.CustomerId = a.CustomerId")
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you copy your data.frames from the list to a new environment, then you can use the `envir` argument to `sqldf` or by naming the elements of the list, and using `with`.

Note a couple of things:

- I create `dflist` using `list` not `c`.

note the difference

```
str(c(df1,df2))
##List of 4
## $ CustomerId: int [1:6] 1 2 3 4 5 6
## $ Product   : Factor w/ 2 levels "Radio","Toaster": 2 2 2 1 1 1
## $ CustomerId: num [1:3] 2 4 6
## $ State     : Factor w/ 2 levels "Alabama","Ohio": 1 1 2

str(list(df1,df2))
##List of 2
## $ :'data.frame': 6 obs. of  2 variables:
##  ..$ CustomerId: int [1:6] 1 2 3 4 5 6
##  ..$ Product   : Factor w/ 2 levels "Radio","Toaster": 2 2 2 1 1 1
## $ :'data.frame': 3 obs. of  2 variables:
##  ..$ CustomerId: num [1:3] 2 4 6
##  ..$ State     : Factor w/ 2 levels "Alabama","Ohio": 1 1 2
```

- I have adjusted the sql queries to reflect the names within the data.frames (as per your second approach)

## the named data

```
dflist <- list(df1,df2)
names(dflist) <- c('df1','df2')
```

### Create a new environment to work in

```
# create a new environment

e <- new.env()
# assign the elements of dflist to this new environment
for(.x in names(dflist)){
  assign(value = dflist[[.x]], x=.x, envir = e)
}

# this could also be done using mapply / lapply
# eg
# invisible(mapply(assign, value = dflist, x = names(dflist), MoreArgs =list(envir = e)))
# run the sql query
sqldf("select a.CustomerId, a.Product, b.State from df1 a
          inner join df2 b on b.CustomerId = a.CustomerId", envir = e)

##  CustomerId Product   State
## 1          2 Toaster Alabama
## 2          4   Radio Alabama
## 3          6   Radio    Ohio
```

## A simpler approach using `with`

you could simply use `with` which evalulates locally (important that dflist is a named list here)

```
# this is far simpler!!
with(dflist,sqldf("select a.CustomerId, a.Product, b.State from df1 a
           inner join df2 b on b.CustomerId = a.CustomerId"))
```

## Another simple approach using `proto`

- Thanks to @G.Grothendieck (see the comments

This uses the `proto` package which is loaded with `sqldf`

```
dflist <- list(a = df1, b = df2)
sqldf( "select a.CustomerId, a.Product, b.State from df1 a 
         inner join df2 b on b.CustomerId = a.CustomerId", 
         envir = as.proto(dflist))
```

## Using data.table

Or you could use `data.table` which gives `sql-like` approaches (see [FAQ 2.16](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/datatable-faq.pdf))

```
library(data.table)
dflist <- list(data.table(df1),data.table(df2))
names(dflist) <- c('df1','df2')
invisible(lapply(dflist, setkeyv, 'CustomerId'))
with(dflist, df1[df2])
##    CustomerId Product   State
## 1:          2 Toaster Alabama
## 2:          4   Radio Alabama
## 3:          6   Radio    Ohio
```

Comment: I've shown how to use `assign` with `mapply` instead of the `for loop`.

Comment: Here is a variation on the `envir=e` approach using proto (which sqldf already pulls in so you don't have to load it separately): `dflist <- list(a = df1, b = df2); sqldf( "select a.CustomerId, a.Product, b.State from df1 a inner join df2 b on b.CustomerId = a.CustomerId", envir = as.proto(dflist))` or we could just create the proto object directly using the sqldf `envir=` argument like this: `envir = proto(a = df1, b = df2)`